# How to clear all the integers in a list if the new appended integer has a smaller value than the largest integer of that list

Tags: python

So I initially have a list of integers:

```
Lst=[10,5,8]
```

When I enter append an integer like say 4 I want the list to be like this:

```
Lst=[4]
```

Since the number 4 is smaller than the previous largest value (10) all the previous integers are removed.

Again, if I append a different value like 12 the list should become like `[4,12]` but I have no idea how to append and delete integers at the same time how should I code this?

Comment: if x < datapoint: Lst = [x] else: Lst.append(x) Nothing special about doing two easy things one after another. Just do it.

Comment: Ah thanks man appreciate it :))

Comment: You could keep track of the largest value? If the value to append is smaller than this largest value, your list would be `[new_value]` otherwise `List.append(new_value)`. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function

```py
def func(l, n):# l is the list, n is the number
    prev_max = max(l)# previous max value
    if n > prev_max:
        l = [n]
    else:
        l.append(n)
    return l
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
elem = 4
if max(lst) < elem:
    lst = [elem]
else:
    lst.append(elem)
```